# SQL "archive" data from 1 table to another table after X days

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, oracle-sqldeveloper

The database i am using is Oracle enterprise.
I have a table for logging the "GPS coordinates" of our workers (column:id, userid,longitute,latitude,date,error, error type).
But for the table to not get clumped up over time i want to have another table "archive GPS coordinates" and i want to automaticly *move* data from 1 table to another after X days.
right now i have 2 ideas how best to do this:

1. every day at 00:00 perform a *scan* of the table and *move* data from the main table to the archive table.
2. insert another column into the main table name "date + X days" and when sysdate = "date + X days" *move* the data to the other table.

at the moment i am leaning for solution #1 since we have a table called "settings" and we can code the *scan* and *move* variable X to be flexible

Any other ideas/recommendation you can give me?

Comment: #1 sounds like how I've seen most people implement this. You might also consider partitioning your table by date to solve the same problem without needing a second table.

Comment: You may want to consider looking into the exchange PARTITION command. Here is a good example https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/partitioning-an-existing-table-using-exchange-partition

Answer (score 0):

If you're licensed for it, I'd check out partitioning.  As the saying goes: "The fastest way to move data is not to move it at all".  Partitioning can assist with ensuring that historical data does not interfere with the performance of the recent data.

A full intro on partitioning to walk you through the options is here

https://asktom.oracle.com/partitioning-for-developers.htm